# Why are there two aliases for my git repo?

Tags: git, github

From what I've seen on other questions "origin" is an alias for your repository which saves you having to type out the entire url, is this right? If so why do I have another alias named "github", both allow me to fetch and push. And is there a way to remove "github"?

```
me$ git remote -v
github  https://github.com/me/app.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/me/app.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/me/app.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/me/app.git (push)
```

What is happening here? I've tried to remove "github", but this doesn't work.

```
git config --global --unset alias.github
```

Comment: It's not about alias, it's just two different remote with same url. And it can be removed by [git remote rm](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emremoveem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've seen on other questions "origin" is an alias for your repository which saves you having to type out the entire url, is this right?

no.
it's not an "alias", it's the *name* of the remote.
`origin` is typically the name of the remote that you originally cloned the repository from. but you can chose other names as well.
a remote *always* has a name.

> If so why do I have another alias named "github",

you don't have another "alias". you have a second remote.
the two remotes happen to share the URL (which is not very common; but why not...).

git is a *decentralised* version control system.
one of the implications of this is that it can have multiple remotes (as in your case) or none at all.

> If so why do I have another alias named "github", both allow me to fetch and push. And is there a way to remove "github"?

yes. *remove* the *remote*:

```sh
git remote remove github
```

git comes with extensive manpages.
to learn more about *remotes* run:

```sh
git remote --help
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had seen the term alias being used to refer to a remote (as I have just learnt), which caused a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an *alias*, it's a *remote*.  Both are technical terms ([jargon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon)): a Git alias is one in the `[alias]` section of the configuration, that your `git config --global --unset` would erase, but a *remote* is a name in a `[remote "name"]` section (which can therefore hold multiple settings—usually there are two here, one for the URL and one as a `fetch` default).

> And is there a way to remove "github"?

Run `git remote remove github`.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>You can also use `git config` to delete the entire section, but along with a remote, you may have some set of *remote-tracking names*, and `git remote remove` will clean everything up, not just the entry in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Seeing the term alias being used incorrectly caused the confusion.